# Meteor: Programmatically generate password reset token?

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, how do you programmatically generate / store a reset password token for a user (outside the context of a user asking for it themselves in the UI)?

I am sending a custom email and would like to embed my own "Reset Password" button within it. This requires me to generate a valid reset password token on my own.

Are there any undocumented Accounts functions / helpers that I'm not aware of that can help me achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most scenarios, I recommend using the in-built [`Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendResetPasswordEmail) for sending the email and overriding [`Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-emailTemplates) to do customizations for the email. For example, you can do a custom reset link like this:

```js
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html = (user, url) =>
  `<a href="${url}" style="{ something cool... }">Reset your password</a>`;
```

However, if you need more customizability than this, there is no ready function for creating the reset token, but if you look at the [source code for `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L559), you'll see that really you only need to insert an object in the `services.password.reset` field of the user object like so:

```js
var token = Random.secret();
var when = new Date();
var tokenRecord = {
  token: token,
  email: email,
  when: when,
  reason: 'reset'
};
Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: {
  "services.password.reset": tokenRecord
}});

var resetPasswordUrl = Accounts.urls.resetPassword(token);
```

Now you can send `resetPasswordUrl` to your user in any way you like, it should work. Be careful with security though - I suppose that the lack of a ready-made function for generating password reset tokens is intentional, and meant to discourage people from carelessly creating password reset methods.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer!

Comment: Glad it helped. Note also that there is a [pull request open for Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/8207) that should improve this functionality, so things here could change in future Meteor versions.